# I get errors when trying to use the "precompileRcppNT2" function in the RcppNT2 package

Tags: rcpp

I wanted to see if the use of SIMD instructions might speed up some of the code that I have.  I loaded the RcppNT2 package and they recommend using the "precompileRcppNT2()" function to speed up the compilation process.  In doing that, I get the following errors and was wondering is there was something I was missing is trying to use the package:

```
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31) -- "Sincere Pumpkin Patch"
Copyright (C) 2016 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

  Natural language support but running in an English locale

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

The following object is masked from package:base:

    setwd

libraries: c:/R/r_libs-3.3.2 C:/R/R-3.3.2/library 
library & Java environment set from C:\Users\jh52822\Documents\.RProfile
> library(devtools)
> library(Rcpp)
> library(RcppNT2)
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] RcppNT2_0.1.0   Rcpp_0.12.7     devtools_1.12.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] withr_1.0.2   memoise_1.0.0 digest_0.6.10
> precompileRcppNT2()
Pre-compiling 'RcppNT2.h'...
In file included from c:/R/r_libs-3.3.2/RcppNT2/include/nt2/bessel/include/functions/j0.hpp:5:0,
                 from c:/R/r_libs-3.3.2/RcppNT2/include/nt2/bessel/functions.hpp:5,
                 from c:/R/r_libs-3.3.2/RcppNT2/include/nt2/bessel/bessel.hpp:5,
                 from c:/R/r_libs-3.3.2/RcppNT2/include/RcppNT2.h:15:
c:/R/r_libs-3.3.2/RcppNT2/include/nt2/bessel/functions/scalar/j0.hpp: In member function 'nt2::ext::impl_j0_<void(boost::dispatch::meta::scalar_<boost::dispatch::meta::double_<Origin> >), boost::dispatch::tag::cpu_>::result_type nt2::ext::impl_j0_<void(boost::dispatch::meta::scalar_<boost::dispatch::meta::double_<Origin> >), boost::dispatch::tag::cpu_>::operator()(const A0&) const':
c:/R/r_libs-3.3.2/RcppNT2/include/nt2/bessel/functions/scalar/j0.hpp:60:14: error: '::_j0' has not been declared
       return ::_j0(a0);
              ^
In file included from c:/R/r_libs-3.3.2/RcppNT2/include/nt2/bessel/include/functions/j1.hpp:5:0,
                 from c:/R/r_libs-3.3.2/RcppNT2/include/nt2/bessel/functions.hpp:6,
                 from c:/R/r_libs-3.3.2/RcppNT2/include/nt2/bessel/bessel.hpp:5,
                 from c:/R/r_libs-3.3.2/RcppNT2/include/RcppNT2.h:15:
c:/R/r_libs-3.3.2/RcppNT2/include/nt2/bessel/functions/scalar/j1.hpp: In member function 'nt2::ext::impl_j1_<void(boost::dispatch::meta::scalar_<boost::dispatch::meta::double_<Origin> >), boost::dispatch::tag::cpu_>::result_type nt2::ext::impl_j1_<void(boost::dispatch::meta::scalar_<boost::dispatch::meta::double_<Origin> >), boost::dispatch::tag::cpu_>::operator()(const A0&) const':
c:/R/r_libs-3.3.2/RcppNT2/include/nt2/bessel/functions/scalar/j1.hpp:74:14: error: '::_j1' has not been declared
       return ::_j1(a0);
              ^
In file included from c:/R/r_libs-3.3.2/RcppNT2/include/nt2/bessel/include/functions/jni.hpp:5:0,
                 from c:/R/r_libs-3.3.2/RcppNT2/include/nt2/bessel/functions.hpp:7,
                 from c:/R/r_libs-3.3.2/RcppNT2/include/nt2/bessel/bessel.hpp:5,
                 from c:/R/r_libs-3.3.2/RcppNT2/include/RcppNT2.h:15:
c:/R/r_libs-3.3.2/RcppNT2/include/nt2/bessel/functions/scalar/jni.hpp: In member function 'nt2::ext::impl_jni_<void(boost::dispatch::meta::scalar_<boost::dispatch::meta::integer_<T> >, boost::dispatch::meta::scalar_<boost::dispatch::meta::double_<A1> >), boost::dispatch::tag::cpu_>::result_type nt2::ext::impl_jni_<void(boost::dispatch::meta::scalar_<boost::dispatch::meta::integer_<T> >, boost::dispatch::meta::scalar_<boost::dispatch::meta::double_<A1> >), boost::dispatch::tag::cpu_>::operator()(const A0&, const A1&) const':
c:/R/r_libs-3.3.2/RcppNT2/include/nt2/bessel/functions/scalar/jni.hpp:63:14: error: '::_jn' has not been declared
       return ::_jn(a0, a1);
              ^
In file included from c:/R/r_libs-3.3.2/RcppNT2/include/nt2/bessel/include/functions/y0.hpp:5:0,
                 from c:/R/r_libs-3.3.2/RcppNT2/include/nt2/bessel/functions.hpp:8,
                 from c:/R/r_libs-3.3.2/RcppNT2/include/nt2/bessel/bessel.hpp:5,
                 from c:/R/r_libs-3.3.2/RcppNT2/include/RcppNT2.h:15:
c:/R/r_libs-3.3.2/RcppNT2/include/nt2/bessel/functions/scalar/y0.hpp: In member function 'nt2::ext::impl_y0_<void(boost::dispatch::meta::scalar_<boost::dispatch::meta::double_<Origin> >), boost::dispatch::tag::cpu_>::result_type nt2::ext::impl_y0_<void(boost::dispatch::meta::scalar_<boost::dispatch::meta::double_<Origin> >), boost::dispatch::tag::cpu_>::operator()(const A0&) const':
c:/R/r_libs-3.3.2/RcppNT2/include/nt2/bessel/functions/scalar/y0.hpp:69:14: error: '::_y0' has not been declared
       return ::_y0(a0);
              ^
In file included from c:/R/r_libs-3.3.2/RcppNT2/include/nt2/bessel/include/functions/yni.hpp:5:0,
                 from c:/R/r_libs-3.3.2/RcppNT2/include/nt2/bessel/functions.hpp:10,
                 from c:/R/r_libs-3.3.2/RcppNT2/include/nt2/bessel/bessel.hpp:5,
                 from c:/R/r_libs-3.3.2/RcppNT2/include/RcppNT2.h:15:
c:/R/r_libs-3.3.2/RcppNT2/include/nt2/bessel/functions/scalar/yni.hpp: In member function 'nt2::ext::impl_yni_<void(boost::dispatch::meta::scalar_<boost::dispatch::meta::integer_<T> >, boost::dispatch::meta::scalar_<boost::dispatch::meta::double_<A1> >), boost::dispatch::tag::cpu_>::result_type nt2::ext::impl_yni_<void(boost::dispatch::meta::scalar_<boost::dispatch::meta::integer_<T> >, boost::dispatch::meta::scalar_<boost::dispatch::meta::double_<A1> >), boost::dispatch::tag::cpu_>::operator()(const A0&, const A1&) const':
c:/R/r_libs-3.3.2/RcppNT2/include/nt2/bessel/functions/scalar/yni.hpp:69:14: error: '::_yn' has not been declared
       return ::_yn(a0, a1);
              ^
In file included from c:/R/r_libs-3.3.2/RcppNT2/include/boost/simd/ieee/include/functions/scalar/nextafter.hpp:5:0,
                 from c:/R/r_libs-3.3.2/RcppNT2/include/boost/simd/include/functions/scalar/nextafter.hpp:4,
                 from c:/R/r_libs-3.3.2/RcppNT2/include/boost/simd/ieee/functions/scalar/next.hpp:15,
                 from c:/R/r_libs-3.3.2/RcppNT2/include/boost/simd/ieee/include/functions/next.hpp:5,
                 from c:/R/r_libs-3.3.2/RcppNT2/include/nt2/ieee/functions/next.hpp:12,
                 from c:/R/r_libs-3.3.2/RcppNT2/include/nt2/ieee/include/functions/next.hpp:4,
                 from c:/R/r_libs-3.3.2/RcppNT2/include/nt2/ieee/functions.hpp:27,
                 from c:/R/r_libs-3.3.2/RcppNT2/include/nt2/ieee/ieee.hpp:5,
                 from c:/R/r_libs-3.3.2/RcppNT2/include/RcppNT2.h:26:
c:/R/r_libs-3.3.2/RcppNT2/include/boost/simd/ieee/functions/scalar/nextafter.hpp: In member function 'boost::simd::ext::impl_nextafter_<void(boost::dispatch::meta::scalar_<boost::dispatch::meta::double_<Origin> >, boost::dispatch::meta::scalar_<boost::dispatch::meta::double_<Origin> >), boost::dispatch::tag::cpu_>::result_type boost::simd::ext::impl_nextafter_<void(boost::dispatch::meta::scalar_<boost::dispatch::meta::double_<Origin> >, boost::dispatch::meta::scalar_<boost::dispatch::meta::double_<Origin> >), boost::dispatch::tag::cpu_>::operator()(const A0&, const A0&) const':
c:/R/r_libs-3.3.2/RcppNT2/include/boost/simd/ieee/functions/scalar/nextafter.hpp:73:14: error: '::_nextafter' has not been declared
       return ::_nextafter(a0, a1);
              ^
Error: Failed to compile 'RcppNT2.h'
In addition: Warning message:
running command 'c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/g++ -x c++-header c:/R/r_libs-3.3.2/RcppNT2/include/RcppNT2.h -Ic:/R/r_libs-3.3.2/RcppNT2/include -I c:/R/r_libs-3.3.2/BH/include -IC:/R/R-3.3.2/include -std=c++11 -O2 -Wall -mtune=core2' had status 1
```

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Looks your MinGW version does not support the raw bessel and nextafter function or the version of NT2 used by RCpp is not packing the math config header that should take care of this.

Not sure how RCpp is precompiled but it should be done so that on MinGW BOOST_SIMD_HAS_YN is defiend and BOOST_SIMD_HAS__YN is undefined.